# puppet onlyif logical expression

Tags: puppet, facter

I am trying to set up a Puppet `exec` resource for a Windows Server based on a Facter variable. But, it looks like `onlyif` accepts only command files and not an inline expression.

Could someone please help me set this expression in `onlyif` (either as a conditional expression or as inline-dos command)

```
exec { 'C:\Users\validate.cmd validate':
  onlyif   =>  "$validate_enabled" == true,   => This not recognized as command
  provider => powershell,
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple issues here. The first is that the syntax for the `onlyif` is incorrect. That attribute executes a command and checks for success, so you would want to change it to this to remove Puppet string and shell syntax issues:

```
exec { 'C:\Users\validate.cmd validate':
  onlyif   => $validate_enabled,
  provider => powershell,
}
```

Note the first part of what I wrote (executes a command). You do not want to execute a command in this instance. You want to check the value of a boolean Facter fact. Therefore, you would be checking this with Puppet DSL and not a shell command.

Facter 3/Puppet 4:

```
# use fact hash
if $facts['validate_enabled'] {
  exec { 'C:\Users\validate.cmd validate': provider => powershell }
}
```

Facter 2/Puppet 3:

```
# specify global variable for safety
if $::validate_enabled {
  exec { 'C:\Users\validate.cmd validate': provider => powershell }
}
```

This will fix your conditional and give you your desired behavior.